# how to retreive a list of filenames from a directory without the file extension

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, directory

I have a powershell command I use frequently to obtain a list of files in a specific directory

dir -name > filenames.txt

Output

filename.pdf
filename2.pdf

This however creates a list with the file extensions. Is there a simple way I can run a single line command that returns the file names not including the file extensions.

I would like the result to be like the following

filename
filename2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
(Get-ChildItem | Select -Expand BaseName) >filenames.txt
```

`Basename` property gets the file name without extension.